# Assign directive values in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm working with angularjs and I have this directive:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
     return {
     restrict: 'C',
     templateUrl: 'hola.html'
   };
});
```

And here is the controller:

```
.controller('demoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.directive ='my-customer';
})
```

And my problem is that this statement, in the HTML, doesnt works:

```
<div class="{{directive}}"></div>
```

But it works with this other one:

```
<div class="my-customer"></div>
```

Is there any way to call dynamically to the directive?

PD: Excuse my english and thanks to the stackoverflowers for editing my texts and make them coherent.

Edit: Maybe I havent explain myself but I want to call the directive with {{variable}}.

```
                       Gonzalo
```

Comment: Have you noticed the difference between my-customer and {{directive}}=>myCustomer?

Comment: Yeah, sorry it was a type error.

Comment: hm, that's actually quite hard task. What you need to do is call $compile for that div after html was rendered and actual value from controller was put into 'class' attribute.
Some docs that might help you:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView (see events section).

Comment: Do you have to use 'class' attribute or custom attribute would work too ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
       .directive('myCustomer', function() {
             return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateUrl: 'hola.html'  

 };
})
```

In template use like this,

```
<my-customer></my-customer>
```